# Implementing global extendable / overridable ajax loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I'm currently displaying an ajax loading image whenever a jquery ajax request occurs like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
 $(".ajaxLoadingIndicator").show();
  });

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
  $(".ajaxLoadingIndicator").hide();
 });
```

I can put this in a global JS file and have it on every page. Now it would be smart to make this behavior overridable at certain points. A sub-view or page might execute additional logic or replace the current logic entirely. Currently I'm doing something like this:

//global js file

```
var shsGlobal = new Globals();

function Globals() {

}

Globals.prototype.ajaxLoaderStart = function () {
    $(".ajaxLoadingIndicator").show();
}

Globals.prototype.ajaxLoaderStop = function () {
    $(".ajaxLoadingIndicator").hide();
}


$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
shsGlobal.ajaxLoaderStart();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
shsGlobal.ajaxLoaderStop();
});
```

And on a different page I might do sth like this:

```
   shsGlobal.ajaxLoaderStart = function () {
    //additional logic here...

    //base method
    Globals.prototype.ajaxLoaderStart.call();
}
```

Since I'm not doing that much javascript I'm not sure if this isn't a bit wonky. It works, though.

Comment: I have used/seen this is projects, and yes it works. Did you have any particular question about the implementation? for code review I guess  codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place.

Comment: I don't see a question?

Comment: @AlokSwain you are right. I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Should go to codereview.stackexchange.com